# Recurring Kernel Panic on iMac (Retina 5K, 27-inch, 2017)

Tags: imac, kernel-panic

When I return to my computer—usually in the morning or evening after having used it all day—I find that my computer was restarted due to a Kernel Panic. It’s an older iMac but I would like to know what causes these panics so that I can swap out a part or fix a hardware issue if needed.

What is the cause of these issues? If you cannot tell from this info, how can I find it?

[image: Kernel Panic Screenshot]

```
panic(cpu 1 caller 0xffffff801fdf9a25): userspace watchdog timeout: no successful checkins from com.apple.logd in 120 seconds
service returned not alive with context : unresponsive dispatch queue(s): com.apple.firehose.io-wl 
service: com.apple.logd, total successful checkins since load (532570 seconds ago): 53245, last successful checkin: 120 seconds ago
service: com.apple.WindowServer, total successful checkins since load (532510 seconds ago): 53250, last successful checkin: 0 seconds ago

Backtrace (CPU 1), Frame : Return Address
0xffffffb900d53670 : 0xffffff801ca8e0dd 
0xffffffb900d536c0 : 0xffffff801cbd4f33 
0xffffffb900d53700 : 0xffffff801cbc552a 
0xffffffb900d53750 : 0xffffff801ca32a2f 
0xffffffb900d53770 : 0xffffff801ca8d8fd 
0xffffffb900d53890 : 0xffffff801ca8dbf3 
0xffffffb900d53900 : 0xffffff801d29d884 
0xffffffb900d53970 : 0xffffff801fdf9a25 
0xffffffb900d53980 : 0xffffff801fdf9660 
0xffffffb900d539a0 : 0xffffff801d21e13e 
0xffffffb900d539f0 : 0xffffff801fdf8a34 
0xffffffb900d53b20 : 0xffffff801d22837b 
0xffffffb900d53c80 : 0xffffff801cb80961 
0xffffffb900d53d90 : 0xffffff801ca9375d 
0xffffffb900d53e00 : 0xffffff801ca69cf5 
0xffffffb900d53e60 : 0xffffff801ca81312 
0xffffffb900d53ef0 : 0xffffff801cba982d 
0xffffffb900d53fa0 : 0xffffff801ca33216 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.driver.watchdog(1.0)[C29AFC04-7113-39AA-80DF-00F4DDAD0F46]@0xffffff801fdf7000->0xffffff801fdf9fff

Process name corresponding to current thread: watchdogd

Mac OS version:
20F71

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 20.5.0: Sat May  8 05:10:33 PDT 2021; root:xnu-7195.121.3~9/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 52A1E876-863E-38E3-AC80-09BBAB13B752
KernelCache slide: 0x000000001c800000
KernelCache base:  0xffffff801ca00000
Kernel slide:      0x000000001c810000
Kernel text base:  0xffffff801ca10000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff801c900000
System model name: iMac18,3 (Mac-BE088AF8C5EB4FA2)
System shutdown begun: NO
Panic diags file available: YES (0x0)
Hibernation exit count: 0

System uptime in nanoseconds: 532584374600265
Last Sleep:           absolute           base_tsc          base_nano
  Uptime  : 0x0001e461f67604de
  Sleep   : 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
  Wake    : 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000663c5c54a 0x0000000000000000
last started kext at 423476011186511: @plugin.IOAVBDiscoveryPlugin  940.4 (addr 0xffffff7fb7768000, size 32768)
last stopped kext at 507336016263: >!AFIVRDriver    4.1.0 (addr 0xffffff7fb604b000, size 8192)
loaded kexts:
>!ATopCaseHIDEventDriver    4050.1
>AudioAUUC  1.70
>AGPM   122.1
>!APlatformEnabler  2.7.0d0
>X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
@fileutil   20.036.15
@filesystems.autofs 3.0
@fsplaceholder  1.14.0
>!AUpstreamUserClient   3.6.8
@kext.AMDFramebuffer    4.0.5
>!AHDA  283.15
@kext.AMDRadeonX4000    4.0.5
@kext.AMDRadeonServiceManager   4.0.5
>!A!IKBLGraphics    16.0.4
>eficheck   1
>!AGraphicsDevicePolicy 6.3.3
@AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics   6.3.3
>!AGFXHDA   100.1.433
>pmtelemetry    1
|IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
>usb.!UUserHCI  1
|IO!BSerialManager  8.0.5d7
@Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
>!AHV   1
>!ADiskImages2  1
>!A!IPCHPMC 2.0.1
>!A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
>!AThunderboltIP    4.0.3
@kext.AMD9500!C 4.0.5
|Broadcom!B20703USBTransport    8.0.5d7
>!ASMCLMU   212
>!A!IKBLGraphicsFramebuffer 16.0.4
>!AMCCSControl  1.14
|IO!BUSBDFU 8.0.5d7
>!AFileSystemDriver 3.0.1
@filesystems.tmpfs  1
@filesystems.hfs.kext   556.100.11
@BootCache  40
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
@filesystems.apfs   1677.120.9
>!ASDXC 1.9.0
|!ABCM5701Ethernet  11.0.0
>AirPort.BrcmNIC    1400.1.1
>!AAHCIPort 346.100.2
@private.KextAudit  1.0
>!AACPIButtons  6.1
>!ARTC  2.0
>!ASMBIOS   2.1
>!AACPIEC   6.1
>!AAPIC 1.7
@!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
@nke.applicationfirewall    311
|IOKitRegistryCompatibility 1
|EndpointSecurity   1
@plugin.IOAVBDiscoveryPlugin    940.4
>!AActuatorDriver   4440.3
>!AHIDKeyboard  224
>!AMultitouchDriver 4440.3
>!AInputDeviceSupport   4400.35
>!AHS!BDriver   4050.1
>IO!BHIDDriver  8.0.5d7
@kext.triggers  1.0
@kext.AMDRadeonX4200HWLibs  1.0
>DspFuncLib 283.15
@kext.OSvKernDSPLib 529
@kext.AMDRadeonX4000HWServices  4.0.5
>!AGraphicsControl  6.3.3
|IOSerial!F 11
|IOAVB!F    940.4
@plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    985.2
|IOEthernetAVB!C    1.1.0
>!AHDA!C    283.15
|IOHDA!F    283.15
|IOAudio!F  300.6.1
@vecLib.kext    1.2.0
@!AGPUWrangler  6.3.3
|IONDRVSupport  585.1
|IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F   1.0.0
>!AThunderboltDPOutAdapter  8.1.4
@kext.AMDSupport    4.0.5
>X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
>IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
|Broadcom!BHost!CUSBTransport   8.0.5d7
|IO!BHost!CUSBTransport 8.0.5d7
|IO!BHost!CTransport    8.0.5d7
|IOAccelerator!F2   442.9
@!AGraphicsDeviceControl    6.3.3
>!ASMBusPCI 1.0.14d1
|IOGraphics!F   585.1
>!ASMBus!C  1.0.18d1
>usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
>usb.cdc    5.0.0
>usb.networking 5.0.0
>usb.!UHostCompositeDevice  1.2
>!AThunderboltDPInAdapter   8.1.4
>!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F   8.1.4
>!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    4.1.1
>!AHPM  3.4.4
>!A!ILpssI2C!C  3.0.60
>!A!ILpssDmac   3.0.60
>!ABSDKextStarter   3
|IOSurface  290.8.1
@filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
>!AXsanScheme   3
|IOAHCIBlock!S  332
>!AThunderboltNHI   7.2.8
|IOThunderbolt!F    9.3.2
|IO80211!F  1200.12.2b1
|IOSkywalk!F    1
>mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
>corecapture    1.0.4
|IONVMe!F   2.1.0
>!A!ILpssI2C    3.0.60
>usb.!UHostPacketFilter 1.0
|IOUSB!F    900.4.2
|IOAHCI!F   294.100.1
>!A!ILpssGspi   3.0.60
>usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UXHCI 1.2
>!AEFINVRAM 2.1
>!AEFIRuntime   2.1
|IOSMBus!F  1.1
|IOHID!F    2.0.0
$!AImage4   3.0.0
|IOTimeSync!F   985.2
|IONetworking!F 3.4
>DiskImages 493.0.0
|IO!B!F 8.0.5d7
|IOReport!F 47
|IO!BPacketLogger   8.0.5d7
$quarantine 4
$sandbox    300.0
@kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
|CoreAnalytics!F    1
>!ASSE  1.0
>!AKeyStore 2
>!UTDM  511.120.2
|IOUSBMass!SDriver  184.121.1
|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  436.121.1
|IO!S!F 2.1
|IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  436.121.1
>!AMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
@kext.CoreTrust 1
>!AFDEKeyStore  28.30
>!AEffaceable!S 1.0
>!ACredentialManager    1.0
>KernelRelayHost    1
|IOUSBHost!F    1.2
>!UHostMergeProperties  1.2
>usb.!UCommon   1.0
>!ABusPower!C   1.0
>!ASEPManager   1.0.1
>IOSlaveProcessor   1
>!AACPIPlatform 6.1
>!ASMC  3.1.9
|IOPCI!F    2.9
|IOACPI!F   1.4
>watchdog   1
@kec.pthread    1
@kec.corecrypto 11.1
@kec.Libm   1
```

- iMac (Retina 5K, 27-inch, 2017)
- Processor: 3.4 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i5
- Memory: 24 GB 2400 MHz DDR4
- Graphics: Radeon Pro 570 4 GB

**Modifications**:

I added more RAM, see configuration below.

```
Memory Slot  | Size | Type         | Speed    | Status
------------------------------------------------------
BANK 0/DIMM0 | 4GB  | DDR4 SO-DIMM | 2400 MHz | OK
BANK 0/DIMM1 | 8GB  | DDR4 SO-DIMM | 2400 MHz | OK
BANK 1/DIMM0 | 4GB  | DDR4 SO-DIMM | 2400 MHz | OK
BANK 1/DIMM1 | 8GB  | DDR4 SO-DIMM | 2400 MHz | OK
```

[image: RAM configuration]

Comment: Did this start after the RAM upgrade, a different hardware upgrade, or use of an external monitor?  FYI, this will be difficult to determine and there's a [1.5yo thread on Macrumors](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/constant-kernel-panics-userspace-watchdog-timeout-no-successful-checkins-from-com-apple-windowserver.2222878/) about this with no successfully conclusion yet.

Comment: @fsb no it started randomly, but this iMac has always had issues with bluetooth. I’ll check out that thread.